# React + Node/Express | Rendering a PDF binary stream blob in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blob, fetch

In React I have hyperlinks which initiate a fetch for PDF files from a backend Node server with Express. The issue is that the stream opens a new window of binary text instead of a PDF file.

React frontend:

```
//Link
    <a href={'#'} onClick={() => this.renderPDF(row.row.pdfid)}> {row.row.commonName}.pdf</a>

//Fetch call
    renderPDF = (pdfLink) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/pdf' + '?q=' + pdfLink, {
            method: 'GET'
            //credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
            .then(url => window.open(url))
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            }));

    }
```

Node backend:

```
app.get('/pdf', (req, res) => {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.query["q"]);
    let chunks = [];

    // When the stream is done being read, end the response
    readStream.on('close', () => {
        res.end()
    })

    // Stream chunks to response
    readStream.pipe(res)
});
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is readStream? where it is defined?

Comment: I edited the post to highlight what's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating your code,

```
app.get('/pdf', (req, res) => {
 let readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.query["q"]);
 let stat = fs.statSync(req.query["q"]);

 // When the stream is done being read, end the response
 readStream.on('close', () => {
     res.end()
 })

 // Stream chunks to response
 res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
 res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=test.pdf');
 readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Try with this now. Also, check if you get the query['q'] and is not undefined or empty just to validate on error side.

Comment: I'm not using readFile, I'm doing a file stream with readStream. My files will be large, so I don't want to load the entire file in memory, but rather use chunks.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Sorry I had thought the res.setHeader statements were specific to readFile

Comment: Sorry, my account hasn't unlocked upvoting yet.

Comment: No worries. Problem solved is what upvote for me. No worries.